ACF image slider in WordPress loop
I have a problem and I can't get the images of each post in a wp loop.
This code goes inside a wordpress loop that pulls all the real estate type posts and each one has an acf image slider.
With this code I get all the images of all posts in the first post of the loop and what I want is that in each post I get the respective images.
Also that 20 as limit of images in the for, it should be a count() but I don't know how to approach it so that it takes out all the images.
The ACF images are individual images, not galleries.
Thank you very much for your help and best regards to all.
function foto_slider($post_id) {
    $featured_image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full');
    $imagenes = [];
    $get_the_ID = get_the_ID();

    if ($get_the_ID == $post_id) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
            $imagen = get_field('foto' . $i, $post_id);
            if ($imagen) {
                $imagenes[] = $imagen;
            }
        }
    }

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slides">
                    <?php if ($featured_image_url): ?>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url($featured_image_url); ?>" alt="Featured image">
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($imagenes as $imagen): ?>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url($imagen['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($imagen['alt']); ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="prev">❮</button>
            <button class="next">❯</button>
        </div>

        <div class="slider-counter">
            <span id="currentSlide">1</span>/<span id="totalSlides"></span>
            <span class="dashicons dashicons-camera-alt"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>

        .slider-container {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 600px;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .slider {
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .slides {
            display: flex;
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
        }

        .slide {
            min-width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .slide img {
            width: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
        }

        .slide:hover img {
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }

        .prev, .next {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            background-color: transparent;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 50%;
            padding: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 2;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        .prev {
            left: 10px;
        }

        .next {
            right: 10px;
        }

        .slider-counter {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            color: white;
            padding: 2px 4px;
            font-size: 12px;
            z-index: 2;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        
    .dashicons-camera-alt:before {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 4px;
        font-size: 0.7em;        
    }

        .slider-wrapper::before, .slider-wrapper::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100px;
            z-index: 1;
            pointer-events: none;
            transition: background 0.3s ease;
        }

        .slider-wrapper::before {
            left: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(106, 105, 105, 0.4), transparent);
        }

        .slider-wrapper::after {
            right: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(106, 105, 105, 0.4), transparent);
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var slideIndex = 0;
            var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
            var totalSlides = slides.length;
            var prevButton = document.querySelector('.prev');
            var nextButton = document.querySelector('.next');
            var currentSlide = document.getElementById('currentSlide');
            var totalSlidesElement = document.getElementById('totalSlides');
            totalSlidesElement.textContent = totalSlides;
            function showSlide(index) {
                if (index >= totalSlides) {
                    slideIndex = 0;
                } else if (index < 0) {
                    slideIndex = totalSlides - 1;
                } else {
                    slideIndex = index;
                }
                var offset = -slideIndex * 100;
                console.log("Mostrando slide:", slideIndex, "Offset:", offset);
                document.querySelector('.slides').style.transform = 'translateX(' + offset + '%)';
                currentSlide.textContent = slideIndex + 1;
            }
            nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                showSlide(slideIndex + 1);
            });
            prevButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                showSlide(slideIndex - 1);
            });
            showSlide(slideIndex);
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}


To solve this, we'll need to:
Adjust how the get_field() function retrieves images for each post.
Dynamically count the number of images so that it automatically loops through the available images, rather than using a fixed count of 20.
Updated Code
function foto_slider($post_id) {
// Get the featured image URL
$featured_image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full');
$imagenes = [];

// Loop through ACF fields for the post and collect images dynamically
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    $imagen = get_field('foto' . $i, $post_id);
    if ($imagen) {
        $imagenes[] = $imagen;
    }
}

if (empty($imagenes) && !$featured_image_url) {
    // If no images are found, return early (optional)
    return '';
}

ob_start();
?>
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slides">
                <?php if ($featured_image_url): ?>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($featured_image_url); ?>" alt="Featured image">
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php foreach ($imagenes as $imagen): ?>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($imagen['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($imagen['alt']); ?>" />
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="prev">❮</button>
        <button class="next">❯</button>
    </div>

    <div class="slider-counter">
        <span id="currentSlide">1</span>/<span id="totalSlides"></span>
        <span class="dashicons dashicons-camera-alt"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    /* Slider styles here */
</style>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var slideIndex = 0;
        var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
        var totalSlides = slides.length;
        var prevButton = document.querySelector('.prev');
        var nextButton = document.querySelector('.next');
        var currentSlide = document.getElementById('currentSlide');
        var totalSlidesElement = document.getElementById('totalSlides');
        totalSlidesElement.textContent = totalSlides;
        function showSlide(index) {
            if (index >= totalSlides) {
                slideIndex = 0;
            } else if (index < 0) {
                slideIndex = totalSlides - 1;
            } else {
                slideIndex = index;
            }
            var offset = -slideIndex * 100;
            document.querySelector('.slides').style.transform = 'translateX(' + offset + '%)';
            currentSlide.textContent = slideIndex + 1;
        }
        nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            showSlide(slideIndex + 1);
        });
        prevButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            showSlide(slideIndex - 1);
        });
        showSlide(slideIndex);
    });
</script>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();

}

I have reached the same result before, the one that you have put I had it identical and it works perfectly inside a single entry but it does not work in a loop of archive of entries or in this case of a cpt of properties, which is what I need it for.
Thank you very much for the answer.
